# grails 2.2.4 and grails-spring-security-facebook plugin with GPmongoDB 1.3.0GA

Tags: facebook, mongodb, grails, plugins, spring-security

When i use grails spring security facebook plugin with MongoDB database, it keep throwing OptimisticLockingException on [these section](https://github.com/splix/grails-spring-security-facebook/blob/master/src/groovy/com/the6hours/grails/springsecurity/facebook/DefaultFacebookAuthDao.groovy#L64).

Then i override it with FacebookAuthService like these.

```
class FacebookAuthService {

    def create(FacebookAuthToken token) {

        FacebookUser fbUser = new FacebookUser(uid: token.uid)
        fbUser.accessToken = token.accessToken?.accessToken
        fbUser.accessTokenExpires = token.accessToken?.expireAt

        Facebook facebook = new FacebookTemplate(token.accessToken.accessToken)
        FacebookProfile fbProfile = facebook.userOperations().userProfile
        User user = User.findByUsernameOrFacebookId(fbProfile.email,fbProfile.id)
        if(!user){
            user = new User()
            user.facebookId = fbProfile.id
            user.firstname = fbProfile.firstName.toLS()
            user.lastname = fbProfile.lastName.toLS()
            user.gender = Gender.strToEnum(fbProfile.gender)
            user.acceptTerms = true
            user.acceptTermsDate = new Date()
            user.accountExpired = false
            user.passwordExpired = false
            user.accountLocked = false
            user.enabled = true
            user.username = "facebook_$token.uid"
            user.password = token.accessToken.accessToken
        }else{
            user.facebookId = fbProfile.id
        }

        user.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

        fbUser.user = user

        Role role = Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_USER')
        if (role && !user.authorities.contains(role)) {
            UserRole.create(user, role)
        }

        fbUser.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

        return fbUser

    }

    def getAppUser(FacebookUser facebookUser){
        return facebookUser?.user
    }

    Collection<GrantedAuthority> getRoles(User user){
        return UserRole.findAllByUser(user)?.role?.collect{ role ->
            new GrantedAuthorityImpl(role.authority)
        }
    }
}
```

But now it throws Connection wait timeout after 120000 ms. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Connection wait timeout after 120000 ms

I know there is [bug](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPMONGODB-307) with GPMONGODB driver. and fixed it like described on there.

Please help me to fix it

- Grails version 2.2.4
- mongodb version 2.2.4
- gpmongo driver version 1.3.0GA
- spring security facebook plugin version :0.14.5
  also it includes thse additional plugins to collect user information.
- 'org.springframework.social:spring-social-core:1.0.3.RELEASE'
- 'org.springframework.social:spring-social-facebook:1.0.3.RELEASE'

Edit:
I found out the cause 
com.the6hours.grails.springsecurity.facebook.FacebookAuthProvider class's authenticate method keeps calling on every request. So what could be the cause of this loop ?

Comment: As I see from Jira, it's fixed in gpmongo 1.3.1GA. Did you try with new version?

Comment: but it says 1.3.1 isn't released yet http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPMONGODB

Comment: So, if it's driver bug, what workaround you're expecting?